# JDK 1.7 on AIX Operating System

Tags: java-7, aix

Can somebody tell me how to install JDK 1.7 on AIX operating system?

What I would like to do is install it in a user accessible directory (for example --prefix=/home/raj) instead of the standard system location.

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 4):

IBM provides it's own JDK's for AIX and system Z
Take a look [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/)

Comment: Thanks. That is where I went to look for JDK for AIX. Is there a way to install it in a non-standard user location (for example in a user's home directory rather than a system directory)?

Comment: It's been a while since I did this, but, I am pretty sure it is just a matter of setting the JAVA_HOME variable to point to the location you place the files in and then include the bin dir in your path.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like some tool like installp needs to be used along with the prefix directory.

Answer (score 1):

On the [Java download page at IBM](https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/preLogin.do?source=dka&S_PKG=aix64j7r1&S_TACT=105AGX05&S_CMP=JDK) (you need to register for free to get there) at the bottom you will find some .bin files. These are self-extracting scripts that let you install Java anywhere you like, under any username.

The installp versions can normally only be used by root user.

Answer (score 1):

LATEST REDISTRIBUTION - .BIN
Latest code
jre764redist.7.0.0.145.bin  (108894308)

[image]

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.aix.71.doc/user/ia_install_attended.html

Completing an attended installation
Install the product from an InstallAnywhere package, in an interactive way.

Before you begin
Check the following conditions before you begin the installation process:
You must have a user ID with root authority.
Procedure
Download the installation package file to a temporary directory.
Change to the temporary directory.
Start the installation process by typing ./package.bin at a shell prompt, where package is the name of the package that you are installing.
Select a language from the list shown in the installer window, then click Next. The list of available languages is based on the locale setting for your system.
Read the license agreement, using the scroll bar to reach the end of the license text. To proceed with the installation you must accept the terms of the license agreement. To accept the terms, select the radio button, then click OK.
Note: You cannot select the radio button to accept the license agreement until you have read to the end of the license text.
You are asked to choose the target directory for the installation. If you do not want to install into the default directory, click Choose to select an alternative directory, by using the browser window. When you have chosen the installation directory, click Next to continue.
You are asked to review the choices that you made. To change your selection, click Previous. If your choices are correct, click Install to proceed with installation.
When the installation process is complete, click Done to finish.
Parent topic: Installing from an InstallAnywhere package